# height set to "auto" not working with JS animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried to set the height to "auto" in the code below in order for the DIV to adapt its size based on the content. Unfortunately that doesn't work. (no issue if I set the height in px). Any idea why and how to fix this? Many thanks

**[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/rnjea41y/3/)**.

JS

```
$("a").click(function () {
    var page = $(this).data("page");
    if ($('div:animated').id != page) {
        var active = $(".fold.active");

        // if there is visible fold element on page (user already clicked at least once on link)
        if (active.length) {
            active.animate({
                width: "0"
            }, 200)
                .animate({
                height: "0"
            }, 200, function () {
                // this happens after above animations are complete
                $(this).removeClass("active");

            })

            // clicking for the first time
        }
        if (active.attr("id") != page) {
            $("#" + page)
                .addClass("active")
                .animate({
                height: "auto"
            }, 1000, 'linear')
                .animate({
                width: "200px"
            }, 400, 'linear')

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to calculate the `height` for the jQuery `animate()` to take place

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/7hcsv5dn/

```
var el = $("#" + page)
autoHeight = el.height(),
    $("#" + page)
    .addClass("active")
    .animate({
        height: autoHeight
     }, 1000, function () {
        el.height('auto');
     })
     .animate({
        width: "200px"
     }, 400, 'linear')
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to take some time to calculate the height. Is there a way to do that "in the background"? Many thanks